# Rails - ActionController::UnknownFormat when saving and not signed in with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

The idea behind my project is for users to be able to login and manage waiting lists containing members container in the Members model. Everything requires a user to be logged in, apart from adding new members to the waiting lists.

At the top of my members controller I have the following:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:new, :create]
```

to allow memebers to created by anyone, however when creating a member when not logged in I get the following error:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat

on the following line in the members controller.

```
respond_to do |format|
```

My create action looks as follows:

```
def create
@member = Member.new(member_params)
if !user_signed_in?
  @member.date_added = Time.now
  @member.status = 1
  respond_to do |format|
    if @member.save
      redirect_to(:back)
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @member.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    if @member.save
      format.html { redirect_to @member, notice: 'Member was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @member }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @member.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
end
```

It all works fine when logged in, however only throws up this error when not logged in. Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in redirect_to(:back) when request is JSON.

Try to replace it with:

```
#redirect_to(:back)
format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
format.json { render ..............., status: :created }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forget to give format for `redirect_to(:back)`. Try this

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @member.save
      format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
    else
     ................
```